# JavaScript how can i make a cookie/+1 animation

Tags: javascript

Hi i what to make an image of a cookie plus a string of "+1" to appear and dissapear each time the user clicks the cookie image.

Similair to this website: http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/

You can find my project here: http://www.chri126g.wigf1.sde.dk/Javascript/cookieclicker2/

Right now when you click the cookie the "cookies" increment with 1, how can i make a cookie appear when clicking? with +1? at the spot where my mouse cusor is aswell ?

Please note that i do not nor will i use jQuery :) so please lets discuss clean vanilla JS :)

Answer (score 0):

You should:
 1. on page load load an image of the cookie to be shown/hidden
 2. you can use a library like jquery to do the animation, have a look at
http://api.jquery.com/animate/
you can specify the duration, type of transoformation, etc.

Comment: I don't use jQuery :/

Comment: doing this on your own would probably include making a timer function and manually repositioning the image's position. 
If you can, use any library like jQuery/else, this will make the task much easier.

Comment: Im not talking about "easy"...

Our teacher and all of the other coding teachers at our school tells us to never ever use jQuery, its bloat and only for noobs :)

Answer (score -1):

You could make the text appear/dissapear with the "onclick" event trigger.
If you use jquery you can also animate it like:

```
$(xxxx).fadeIn(1500).fadeOut(1500);
```

Use a hidden div with the text and absolute position so you can make it fade in and out.

Comment: I don't use jQuery :/

Comment: then a simple js add class to add and remove animation: `var d = document.getElementById("div1");
d.className += " otherclass";`

Comment: What didn't happened? the class wasn't added? the effect didn't triggered? you need to be more explicit